# Having problems with Insurance Policy program

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a program which allows input of driver details such as age, occupation and past claims. These 3 factors will have a direct influence on the final premium depending on their value.

My calculations for age and occupation are working fine, it is the claims I am having a problem with. The code below is the calculations carried out on a drivers claim.

I'm not sure why, but the 'totalClaims' variable is updating just fine and the 'difference' variable is too - but the calculations on policy.Premium aren't being carried out when 'difference' is below 1 or between 1 & 5

NOTE

policy is a Policy object

'difference' is years amassed since the claim happened

Premium is a property in Policy. Drivers and Claims are list properties in Policy

```
public void ClaimScanner()
    {
        foreach (Driver driver in policy.Drivers)
        {
            totalClaims = totalClaims + driver.Claims.Count();
            int difference;

            foreach (Claim claim in driver.Claims)
            {
                difference = policy.PolicyStart.Year - claim.ClaimDate.Year;
                if (policy.PolicyStart.Month < claim.ClaimDate.Month || policy.PolicyStart.Month == claim.ClaimDate.Month && policy.PolicyStart.Day < claim.ClaimDate.Day)
                {
                    difference = difference - 1;
                } // gets the "age of a claim"

                if (difference < 1)
                {
                    policy.Premium = policy.Premium * 1.2;
                }

                else if (difference >= 1 && difference < 5)
                {
                    policy.Premium = policy.Premium * 1.1;
                }
                // increases policy price depending on age of claim
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, what *specifically* happens?  Where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the values of the variables when that happens?  What did you expect the behavior or the values to be?  Why?

Comment: Use parenthesis on your if compound statement.  I hate relying on order of operations for things like this because of being burned by them in the past.

Comment: The only way that policy.Premium isn't updated is if difference is out of range when it gets there.  Use your debugger to check the value of difference at that location in the code.  Either that or something else is restoring your policy.Premium value alter in code that we cannot see.

Comment: you are also overwriting the policy.Premium with each loop of the claim

Comment: @David I had never been instructed on how to use breakpoints and debugger until now. Thanks for the help, I was writing the Premium to a csv in a previous method so it wasn't updating after it completed ClaimScanner()

Comment: @Sorceri thanks but that what it's supposed to do with each driver! Sorted the problem now